# How do I edit a single value deep in a JSON object in a JSONB field in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql

So we have a Jsonb field in Postgres that is similar to

```
{
   "entity":[
      {
         "id":"1234",
         "data":[
            {
               "docId":"123456",
               "status":"PENDING"
            },
            {
               "docId":"123457",
               "status":"PENDING"
            },
            {
               "docId":"123458",
               "status":"PENDING"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I wish to update a data object, with doc id = 123457, to a status of "RESOLVED". While not affecting the other statuses'. How can I do this in Postgres?

Our original idea was to read entire document, and then rewrite the JSON object from Java and resave it, but that solution is causing race errors because of a parallel operation for doc id, 123456, that goes off milliseconds before 123457 is called. So I thought maybe if the Json operation is handled in SQL, it might resolve that.

Comment: Normalize your data model and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental problem is a bad data model. If you didn't store these data as a single JSON, but in a normalized database model with several tables and foreign key relationships, the exercise would be trivial.

You can do it in SQL, but that essentially that means unwrapping the JSON into tabular data, modifying those with `jsonb_set` and rebuilding the whole thing, which requires several lateral joins and is too complicated for me to get motivated.

Do it on the client side if that is easier. It is easy to prevent race conditions:

- One option is to use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` whenever you intend to modify the data. Then two such `SELECT`s would lock each other, and the second one would have to wait until the first transaction is done.
- The alternative would be to use a higher transaction isolation level, in this case `REPEATABLE READ`. Then the second transaction would get a *serialization error* when it modifies the data and has to retry the transaction.

Comment: I will give that a go, however that data model in JSON is kinda set in stone at work.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your table is called `"foo"` and the `jsonb` field `"bar"`, you can do this:

```sql
WITH 
e AS (SELECT element, index - 1 AS i 
      FROM foo, jsonb_array_elements(bar -> 'entity') 
      WITH ORDINALITY o (element, index) 
      WHERE element ->> 'id' = '1234'),
f AS (SELECT idx - 1 AS i 
      FROM e, jsonb_array_elements(element -> 'data') 
      WITH ORDINALITY o (elem, idx) 
      WHERE elem ->> 'docId' = '123457')
UPDATE foo
SET bar = jsonb_set(bar, 
                    ARRAY['entity',e.i::text,'data',f.i::text,'status'],
                    '"RESOLVED"', 
                    false) 
FROM e, f 
WHERE bar -> 'entity' -> e.i::int ->> 'id' = '1234';
```

But as the others here say, you should really transform your data into a relational model for this instead of treating JSON like a table :o)